# Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver does not continue after do "GoToUrl" with some pages (google, elmundo.es, etc)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

Package: Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver
Version: 3.12.0, 3.150.0

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
string hello = ""; <-- never come here and not exceptions
```

Answer (score 0):

While using [Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver Version: 3.150.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1990a43a745669e87acb39331a0742979ecc728a/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG#L45) you might face some issues because as per the [*changelog*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1990a43a745669e87acb39331a0742979ecc728a/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG#L65):

> ...Users using this version of the IE driver with language bindings
> prior to 4.0 may encounter issues if the bindings do not properly
> format the new session request; nevertheless, this change will not be
> reverted, as future versions of the language bindings should properly
> format the new session command.

A better option would be to upgrade to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [***v4.0.0.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1990a43a745669e87acb39331a0742979ecc728a/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG#L12)